# How to make Scaffolding work in .Net 7.0 when, The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

**Why do i get certificate not trusted when scaffolding?**

I am running the EF Tools Scaffold-DbContext command and getting the following error:

`A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)`

Here is the command I'm issuing:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SQL.mysite.com;Initial Catalog=db_data;User Id=db_admin;Password=pass123;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true/yes" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "MyDataDbContext" -DataAnnotations -Force`

Can you please help me understand how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

The important part here, is to specify that you trust the server certificate.  Simply include following into the connection string:

`TrustServerCertificate=True`

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 7.0:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SQL.mysite.com;Initial Catalog=db_data;User Id=db_admin;Password=pass123;Persist Security Info=True;Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=yes" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context "MyDataDbContext" -DataAnnotations -Force
```